# redux debugger(flipper plugin) does not work with iOS, works fine on Android. Any solution?

Tags: react-native, redux, flipper

After upgrading

```
react-native-reanimated
```

to

```
2.12.0
```

. I could not use react-native-debugger. Moved to flipper as suggested, but can not find a way to view my redux state. This issue is on iOS. On Android, i am using flipper's plugin redux-debugger and that works.

Is there any workaround to get this fixed on iOS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In recent updates React native now comes with `:hermes_enabled => true` by default in your podfile. I had similar issue few weeks back that i couldn't debug using react-native-debugger for iOS so i set hermes values false in Podfile as `:hermes_enabled => false` and than install the pods again it works good for me.

Comment: i am using flipper, not react-native-debugger anymore. So, i want redux-debugger in flipper plugin to work for iOS as well.